# How to integrate JasperReports Server and Cassandra

Tags: jasper-reports, cassandra, jasperserver

Is there any way to do the subject?

I mean is it possible in theory? Any pluging for the `JasperReports Server` available?

Or maybe there are some other reporting tools that could make something similar job like `JasperReports Server`?

Can not find any info on google.

Comment: looks like there is a way to write own dataprovider and use it for the query to Cassandra http://www.jasperassistant.com/docs/guide/ch03s02.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's a plugin for Cassandra, see: http://jasperforge.org/projects/bigdatareportingfornosqlandhadoop